# How to show Notification in cordova using th plugin cordova-plugin-background-mode?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I tried to install plugin :

> cordova-plugin-local-notifications

but showed **already installed**.

Then I tried

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title:"title",
    text: "Single Notification"
});
```

it results in

> function local not found error
>   then I tried

```
cordova.plugins.localNotifications.schedule({
   id: 1,
   text: "Single Notification"
});
```

It result in

```
function schedule not found error
```

Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to reference cordova.js in your HTML file.

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Once it's referenced you should be able to call the function.

Comment: I referenced 'cordova.js'. Cordova plugins geolocation and background mode are running well.

Comment: "The plugin and its methods are not available before the deviceready event has been fired." - [plugin wiki](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples)